# How to enter multiple inputs into a function?

Tags: functions, input

I'm sorry for asking such an elementary question but I started learning the Mathematica language just yesterday and I can't seem to find an answer anywhere else. I'm trying to calculate the change in the radius of a water molecule as a function of density (Temperature).

```
y[x_]:= \[CubeRoot](3m/4\[Pi]x)
```

here m is a constant. so it basically just boils down to one input, x. previously I simply did it one by one but it's time consuming. is there a way to run multiple inputs  on this simple function? ps; I have no previous programming skills, your help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting there! All you need is a space between your Pi and your x.  As it is you have a Pix which is the name of a variable. Pi x is the same as Pi*x.

If you want to generalize this with mass. You can do this:

```
y[m_, t_]: = (3 Pi)^(1/3) (m t)^(3/2)/2^(2/3)
```

I recommend that you view your functions symbolically when possible.

Your function

```
y[x_] := \[CubeRoot](3 m/4 \[Pi] x)

y[temperature]
```

may not be dividing by x the way you intended.

Have fun exploring.

Comment: Thank you very very Much :) . Is it possible to use this function to map over a list of about 50 different values for T ?  producing 50 different outputs ?

Comment: @Trevz Have a look at `Map` and `Table` in the documentation

Comment: @LukasLang will do, appreciate the help

Comment: In fact, a lot of simple numerical functions (like CubeRoot) has the `Listable` property, you can call your function `y` on a list of data.  `y[{1,2,3}]` will produce 3 values.  But for more complicated functions you might need `Map` and `Table`.